# How to join / concatenate / merge all rows of an RDD in PySpark / AWS Glue into one single long line?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have a protocol that needs to take in many (read millions) of records. The protocol requires all of the data is a single line feed (InfluxDB / QuestDB). Using the InfluxDB client isn't currently an option so I need to do this via a socket.

I am at the end of my ETL process and I now just have to take the final RDD I have created and take all of those rows and transpose them into a single line but can't figure out how to do this (and how to do it properly!)

In PySpark / AWS Glue I currently have:

```py
def write_to_quest(df, measurement, table, timestamp_field, args):
    HOST = args['questdb_host']
    PORT = int(args['questdb_port'])
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        rows = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict(True))
        new_rdd = rows.map(lambda row: 
                                 _row_to_line_protocol(row, measurement, table, timestamp_field)).glom()

        #transform new_rdd to single_line_rdd here

        sock.sendall((single_line_rdd).encode())

    except socket.error as e:
        print("Got error: %s" % (e))
```

Called by:

```py
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

allDaily = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=args['db_name'],
                                                         table_name="daily",
                                                         transformation_ctx="allDaily",
                                                         push_down_predicate="(date_str='20040302' and meter_id='NEM1206106')"
                                                         # for faster testing
                                                         )

# TODO: Handle entire DF as a single payload
df = allDaily.toDF()
tdf = df.withColumn('reading_date_time', F.to_timestamp(df['reading_date_time'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'))
tdf = tdf.drop(*["ingestion_date", "period_start", "period_end", "quality_method",
                 "event", "import_reactive_total", "export_reactive_total"])

write_to_quest(df=tdf, measurement="meter_id", table="daily", timestamp_field="reading_date_time", args=args)
```

The shape of new_rdd is a set of lists of strings:

```
RDD[
['string here,to,join','another string,to,join'...x70]
['string here,to,join','another string,to,join'...x70]
['string here,to,join','another string,to,join'...x70]
x200
]
```

[image]

How do I get this so I have a single line that has everything joined by '\n' (newline)?

e.g:

```
'string here,to,join\nanother string,to,join\n....'
```

I have so far tried several combinations of foreach like:

```
foreach(lambda x: ("\n".join(x)))
```

But to absolutely no avail, I am also concerned about scalability for this - for example I am pretty sure using `.collect()` on millions of rows is going to kill things

So what is the best way to solve this final step?

***Edit after accepted answer***

The specific solution from Werners answer I implemented was this (I removed Glob to get one list item per row and then removed the whitespace (as Influx / Quest is whitespace sensitive)

```py
def write_to_quest(df, measurement, table, timestamp_field, args):
    """
    Open a socket and write the row directly into Quest
    :param df_row:
    :param measurement:
    :param table:
    :param timestamp_field:
    :param args:
    :return:
    """
    HOST = args['questdb_host']
    PORT = int(args['questdb_port'])
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        rows = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict(True))
        new_rdd = rows.map(lambda row:
                            _row_to_line_protocol(row, measurement, table, timestamp_field))
        result = new_rdd.map(lambda r: "".join(r) + "\n") \
            .aggregate("", lambda a, b: a + b, lambda a, b: a + b)
        
        sock.sendall((result.encode()))


    except socket.error as e:
        print("Got error: %s" % (e))

    sock.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row of the rdd can be mapped into one string per row using [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.map.html) and then the result of the map call can be [aggregated](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.aggregate.html) into one large string:

```python
result = rdd.map(lambda r: " ".join(r) + "\n")\
    .aggregate("", lambda a,b: a+b, lambda a,b: a+b)
```

If the goal is to have one large string, all the data has to be moved to a single place at least for the final step. Using `aggregate` here is *slightly* better than collecting all rows and concatinating the strings on the driver as `aggregate` can do things distributed and in parallel for most of the time. However enough memory for the whole final string is still required on a single node.

Comment: This worked like an absolute dream - I have updated my question based on this with the solution that worked for my specific use case above - thank you :)